# Modularize and Reuse asp.net C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to implement a shopping cart website in asp.net C#. The UI and logic implementation is pretty complex.

I want to be able to use this shopping cart application under different ASP.NET websites.

We have 12-15 different websites in asp.net. Each website is a different business model. However, we want the same shopping cart application (with the same UI and logic) to be under each of these websites.

The concept sounds like a ASP.NET Server control i.e create the shopping cart as a ASP.NET server control and plug it in different websites. However, the following are some of the issues we are facing:-

1. The shopping cart UI/logic is pretty complex. Easily can run into 50-60 aspx pages. I am not sure how easy and maintainable will it be  to create this as a server control
2. How much performance impact will we have to face as compared to a standalone shopping cart?

Performance impact is more important for us.

Finally, is there any other better alternative to handle this plug-play design in asp.net for complex projects.

Comment: Classc asp.net or modern mvc? Mvc has a concept for that - i.e. a "subsite" that is integrated (like a forum, a shopping cart) and thus could be copied / shared.

Comment: By "shopping cart", do you mean just the "add to basket/checkout/pay" part of ecommerce, or does it include the catalogue, promotions etc.?

Comment: consider [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) programming. Put what you can into class files that could be imported into each project

Comment: http://blog.longle.net/ -- this guy has a few things about building a modular product, if you're going the MVC route.  You would be able to utilize the shopping cart logic in each app most likely, dependent on how you implement the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want same UI and Logic then these will have to reside at one place only. I am afraid if you create in an usercontrol way, A single usercontrol will be copied to all domain,if you change it then you will have to update on all servers. An easier approach will be creating logic and ui as webservice at a single server.You can costomize it to give html out put which can be called and updated via javascript. However on downside you will have to implement your own session and statemanagement which will be little difficult but will worth it.